# Adding provider agnostic SAML support for iOS app

Tags: ios, saml

I'm looking at adding SAML login support to my app. On web, we support multiple SAML providers, each of which seems to have their own SDK that you can integrate into your app. My question is:

Is there a single SAML SDK I could add to my app that would support all the providers instead of having to add each one individually?

I think I have a good understanding of how the SAML flow works where our own server will return me an authentication URL for the SAML provider once given a login email. I then send the user to that URL and the authenticate. Then *I think* I need to configure each provider with a redirect URL which will be a deeplink back to my app, and then I somehow have to get a token in the app once I open via that deeplink. Does this sound correct?

I'm trying to find more info, but everything I see online is specific to each provider and nothing about a general approach to handling multiple SAML providers.

Any info appreicated.

Comment: You might want to look at [openid](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) rather than SAML. SAML is more complicated and you will probably need a server in the middle. Auth0 or logto are examples

Comment: I have a server in the middle

Comment: Then probably take a look at logto - It will make it easier and simplify the implementation in your iOS app.

Comment: your server in the middle should have its own SAML metadata with its ACS URL. That's how the service providers know where to send the attributes. Providers should all be the same, e.g. SAML WBSSO Profile. The server in the middle acts as your SAML gateway, dealing with the X509 and attribute complexities of SAML. e.g. the phone would use its API to send a user to the appropriate service provider and then be notified when the attributes are ready.